# Could someone share the benchmarks of Radix sort on GTX 580?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, opencl, gpu, radix-sort

Could someone share the benchmarks of Radix sort on GTX 580?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think anyone has published such numbers yet, but the fastest radix sort code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/back40computing/wiki/RadixSorting#Performance).  If you have a GTX 580 then you should be able to run the sorting benchmark using the instructions on that page.

Based on the specifications listed [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-580-us.html) and [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gtx_480_us.html) I'd expect the GTX 580 to be anywhere from 8 to 15% faster than the GTX 480 in radix sort.